# Vertical Alignment of Minipage

Tags: vertical-alignment, titles

I have a question, I'm using the following setup for a title page:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\textsc{\LARGE University Name}\\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\Large Bachelor thesis}\\[2cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Title of the thesis}\\[3cm]
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
 Me\\[0.5cm]
\emph{Student ID:}\\
mine\\[0.5cm]
\emph{Adress:}\\
mine\\[0.5cm]
\emph{Email:}\\
mine
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
mine
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
\vfill
{\large \date{15. Juni 2011}}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

If I run it, the "supervisor" line of the right column does not align with "Author", but rather with the middle of the left column. However, I would like it to be up, with the first item of the left column. How do I do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! As @Gonzalo's answer pointed out, your problem has actually nothing to do with the `titlepage` environment (Removing `\begin{titlepage}` and `\end{titlepage}` won't do anything about it). You might want to change your question title to something like "Vertical alignment of minipage" and tag it accordingly. For some more basic information on `minipage`s take a look at the [Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) (Section 6.6), which is a great reference and introduction to all sorts of things.

Comment: I was trying to accomplish something similar (top-aligning the content of two minipages). In my case, the left minipage contained a figure and I was able to solve the problem by putting a `\vspace{0pt}` at the top of both `minipage`s and using the `[t]` option.

Answer (score 7):

Use the optional argument for the two `minipage`s:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
```

here's how it should look

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\textsc{\LARGE University Name}\\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\Large Bachelor thesis}\\[2cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Title of the thesis}\\[3cm]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
 Me\\[0.5cm]
\emph{Student ID:}\\
mine\\[0.5cm]
\emph{Adress:}\\
mine\\[0.5cm]
\emph{Email:}\\
mine
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
mine
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
\vfill
{\large \date{15. Juni 2011}}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using [t] as an argument actually shifts the lign up a bit, does not align it with the first line of the left minipage.

Comment: @podemos: really? It works for me, see my edited example. If you are getting something different, please add to your question a minimal working example illustrating the problem.

Comment: +1. This is exactly the kind of problem that led to the development of those optional arguments to minipage.