# Align text on a vertical axis similar to movie credits

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I would like to align text on a cover page in a way often seen in movie credits, with the "key" ragged right and the "value" left:

[image]

I use two minipages next to each other to achieve this. However, when I zoom in I see that the vertical alignment of the text is not right:

[image]

How can I get this right?

MWE:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}

Berichterstatter (1. Referent):\par
Mitberichterstatter (2. Referent):\par \vspace*{0.5cm}

Tag der Einreichung:\par
Tag der mündlichen Prüfung: 

\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\hspace{0.2cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}

Prof. Dr. A\par
Prof. Dr. B\par \vspace*{0.5cm}
2. Mai 2013 \par
12. Juli 2013

\end{minipage}
```

Comment: If you think others may encounter the same problem and if you found a solution, don't hesitate to post it as an answer.

Comment: Would you like to have them exactly on the center of the page? If not, you can use a simple `tabular` with alignment `{rl}` so that the first column will have a `right` alignment and the other `left`.

Comment: @Sigur's idea makes sense. The problem with using two `minipage`s is that, in your input file, related data gets separates into two different environments, which may make vertical alignment tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used the `[t]` option for the minipage environment, it worked as wished.

I found the solution here: [Vertical Alignment of Minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20561/vertical-alignment-of-minipage?rq=1)

Comment: The `tabular` approach is much better, trust me.

Comment: I do not see why... the [t] option solves it perfectly.

Comment: @biologue, you are right, it works. The visual effect is the same but when you change the contents to a complexer one it could be tedious to format it, since there is no relation between the corresponding lines of each minipage.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use a `tabular` to do this.

```
\noindent left\dotfill{right} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
Berichterstatter (1. Referent): & Prof. Dr. A \\
Mitberichterstatter (2. Referent): & Prof. Dr. B\\[1em]
Tag der Einreichung: & 2. Mai 2013\\
Tag der mündlichen Prüfung: & 12. Juli 2013 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
left\dotfill{right}
```

[image]

**ps.** the problem is that the vertical which split the columns is not exactly on the center of the page since the whole tabular is being centered.

Answer (score 2):

If the split should be in the middle of the page you can use the the [tabularx](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) environment:

```
\noindent left\dotfill{right}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}XX}
    Berichterstatter (1. Referent): & Prof. Dr. A \\
    Mitberichterstatter (2. Referent): & Prof. Dr. B\\[1em]
    Tag der Einreichung: & 2. Mai 2013\\
    Tag der mündlichen Prüfung: & 12. Juli 2013
\end{tabularx}

\noindent left\dotfill{right}
```

[image]